# JSON Java without break line characters

Tags: java, json, rest, ssl, dropwizard

I've written something in Java. I have a dropwizard resource that returns a JSON object. 
However, I get wrong break line characters.

The correct output in the console looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

The output in the browser, however, like this.

```
"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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\nWblhhToH2uNywGYc8LMReg==\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
```

Can anyone help with the sign \n characters?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior of the encoding and the browser seems to be valid. When you return a JSON object the string is encoded so the new line is represented by \n

any client reading the json attribute will get the string right.

if you want to see the response in the browser, you could return the certificate content as text (content-type: text/plain and not wrapped in json)

Comment: The browser view is only for a test. At the end a java client should receive the JSON packet. Then I can implement it now without any problems. Thank you very much